# Why does Xpdf not work on Windows

Tags: python, pdftotext, xpdf

I am writing a program using invoice2data which requires me to use Xpdf. I am coding on Windows platform. Though I have installed I get the Error message as pdftotext not installed. Can someone help me with why it does not work? I also changed the path in environment variables. Still does not work.

Below is my code

```
def to_text(path):
    """
    Wrapper around Poppler pdftotext.
    """
    if spawn.find_executable("pdftotext"): #shutil.which('pdftotext'):
    out, err = subprocess.Popen(
        ["pdftotext", '-layout', '-enc', 'UTF-8', path, '-'],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
    return out
    else:
    raise EnvironmentError('pdftotext not installed. Can be downloaded from 
    https://poppler.freedesktop.org/')
```

Comment: You may want to include your code so users can review and provide a response

Comment: Included. Thanks

Comment: Is the indentation correct? You're explicitly raising your own errors

Comment: I checked the indentation. While pasting here it changed but otherwise my indentation is right. My module will check for pdftotext and display the error as not installed when not found.